# Setting Up a Repository Using VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have created a repository using VisualSVN and use TortoiseSVN so my friends can check in/out files of the project we're working on. I am able to access the repository on my computer, but my friends are not able to. Anytime my friends try to connect to the repository, they are told

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://[IP ADDRESS]/svn/HyperSpaceBattle'
>   No such host is known.

When setting up a repository, do my friends have to install both VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN in order to access my repository, or do they only need to install TortoiseSVN? Also, are there network settings I have to setup in order for my friends to access my IP Address?

Comment: Your friends only need a SVN client, like TortoiseSVN to work with a repository

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error:

```
No such host is known.
```

The error means that the hostname you enter cannot be resolved to IP address. Check your DNS and network settings.